# Whats the sense of using a AngularJS directive in a comment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, comments, angularjs-directive

Hy,
I am wondering what would be the sense of a AngularJS directive as comment. I found some examples that work where it displays an alert message, even with arguments, but I don't see the sense in a directive used as comment.
Can somebody please give some concrete examples on sense making usage of this feature or explain me the sense of it in some other way?

Thanks

Comment: I think these are for providing support for older browser that down work with custom directives attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use directives as custom tags, attributes or comments.

For custom tags, older versions of IE have problems with them and need extra code to cope with them. This is pretty well documented on the AngularJS site.

I'm not aware of any browsers that have issues with custom attributes, but custom attributes do prevent a page being W3C validated as correct HTML4 or XHTML. If that's important to you, then being able to use directives as comments is valuable.

HTML5 allows for custom attributes beginning with "data-" to be valid though, so it's not an issue for HTML5 pages.